# How to find gender bias in word embeddings?

Tags: python, nlp, linear-algebra, word2vec, word-embedding

I have `glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt` word embeddings. These embeddings in `GloVe` format. I transfered it to `w2v` format using this code:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
"data/glove.twitter.27B.200d.w2v.txt", binary=False
)
```

`len(model.vocab) == 1193514`

There is a gender bias in this word embeddings:

`model.similarity("man", "kitchen") == 0.32785824`

`model.similarity("woman", "kitchen") == 0.40180725`

I want to find a gender bias direction in this word embeddings, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06520.pdf) (Man is to Computer Programmer as Woman is to Homemaker? Debiasing Word Embeddings) method:

> To more robustly estimate bias, we shall aggregate
> across multiple paired comparisons. By combining several directions, such as
> [image]
>
> identify a gender direction `g ∈ R^d` that largely captures gender in the embedding. This direction helps us to quantify direct and indirect biases in words and associations.

So, First, generating some pre-defined pair-differences utilized to generate a gender subspace. Then:

> To identify the gender subspace, we took the ten gender pair difference vectors and computed its principal
> components (PCs). As Figure 6 shows, there is a single direction that explains the majority of variance
> in these vectors. The first eigenvalue is significantly larger than the rest. Note that, from the randomness
> in a finite sample of ten noisy vectors, one expects a decrease in eigenvalues. However, as also illustrated
> in 6, the decrease one observes due to random sampling is much more gradual and uniform. Therefore we
> hypothesize that the top PC, denoted by the unit vector g, captures the gender subspace. In general, the
> gender subspace could be higher dimensional and all of our analysis and algorithms (described below) work
> with general subspaces.
>
> [image]

The generated vector `g` from PC analysis of the generated gender subspace hows the gender bias direction. Finally, to measure the **DirectBias**:

> To measure direct bias, we first identify words that should be gender-neutral for the application in question.
> How to generate this set of gender-neutral words is described in Section 7. Given the gender neutral words,
> denoted by N, and the gender direction learned from above, g, we define the direct gender bias of an embedding to be:
> [image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I determine gender neutral words?

Comment: @Ali My pleasure. You can find a list in the referenced paper as well. The list is not too long (just 10 words). Please note that this list is language-dependent. So, if you are working on a non-English language, you need to provide your own list for your target language.

Answer (score 0):

What word embeddings provide is the ability to trace analogies, an example [here](https://krishansubudhi.github.io/deeplearning/2019/06/13/WordEmbeddings.html), a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09813.pdf)

`v('king') - v('man') ~ v('queen') - v('woman')`

You can even visualize a projection of these vectors in a 2D plot, a great interactive example where you can explore not only gender analogies [here](https://lamyiowce.github.io/word2viz/)

The strategy to find bias is, you hypothesize about some possible bias in the training data, then you look for those analogies that would exist in that biased view but not in a fair/unbiased view.

[image]